# php - Htaccess as fake directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am making a mini blog that could make it's url looks like this:

```
From: http://127.0.0.1/index.php?post=the-story-of-us
To: http://127.0.0.1/view/the-story-of-us
```

I have tried this but i'm getting `404 not found.`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /index\.php\?post=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /view/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not udnerstand your RewriteCondition, but the RewriteRule should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^view/(.*)/? ./index.php?post=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am still getting this: The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: @Jacob I have updated my answer. (Especially removed / from the beginning of view)

Answer (score 0):

Your current rule only handles the case: **Redirect** *old url* to *new url*.
(By the way, +1 for using `THE_REQUEST` to avoid a redirect loop)

You also need to handle the case: **Rewrite** (internally) *new url* to *old url*.
Here is how your htaccess should look like

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect /index.php?post=XXX to /view/XXX
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?post=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /view/%1? [L,R=301]

# Internally rewrite back /view/XXX to /index.php?post=XXX
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)$ /index.php?post=$1 [L]
```